# Database table id-key Null value and referential integrity

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm learning databases, using SQLce. Got some problems, with this error:

```
A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist.
```

How does the integrity and acceptance of data work when attempting to save a data row that does not have specified one foreign key. Isn't it possible to set it to NULL in some way, meaning it will not reference the other table? In case, how would I do that? (For an integer key field)

Also, what if you save a row with a valid foreign key that corresponds to an existing primary key in other table. But then decide to delete that entry in this other table. So the foreign key will no longer be valid. Will I be allowed to delete? How does it work?  I would think it should then be simply reset to a null value.. But maybe it's not that simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is insert your data starting from the parent down.

So if you have an orders table and an items table that refers to orders, you have to create the new order first before adding all the children to the list.

Many of the data access libraries that you can get (in C# there is Linq to SQL) which will try and abstract this problem.

If you need to delete data you actually have to go the other way, delete the items before you delete the parent order record.

Of course, this assumes you are enforcing the foreign key, it is possible to not enforce the key, which might be useful during a bulk delete.

Comment: Thanks! Practically; how/where would one chose to enforce/not the key?

Comment: A key scenario would be legacy data.  You may wish to insert "dirty" data from a legacy system which you will try to clean up.  You would want to reflect that there is a relationship but not actually enforce it when inserting legacy data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of "bad data" you have in the tables. Check if you have all corresponding values in the primary table.

DBMS checks the referential integrity for ensuring the "correctness" of data within database.

For example, if you have a column called **some_id** in **TableA** with values 1 through 10 and a column called **some_id** in **TableB** with values 1 through 11 then **TableA** has no corresponding value (11) for that which you have already in **TableB**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a foreign key nullable but I don't recommend it. There are too many problems and inconsistencies that can arise. Redesign your tables so that you don't need to populate the foreign key for values that don't exist. Usually you can do that by moving the column to a new table for example.